# Public variable value will not transfer between two areas in the same script c#

Tags: c#, variables

My problem is that even though the methods themselves work, the value of the money variable, even though it updates via the "addMoney" function, it's value does not transfer the the "OnMouseDown" method. the value of money will keep rising via the "addMoney" function but will remain 0 in the top function (checked this via debug.logformat) the bools are used to distinguish different buttons, and cCN and sCN are not used yet. All other parts of this script are working, I just need the value of money to communicate between the "addMoney" function to the "OnMouseDown" method. Thanks in advance for any help (and I am new so I am probably missing something obvious.)`

```
public bool cB;
public bool cCB;
public bool sCB;
public bool mB;

private int money;
private int cN;
private int cCN;
private int sCN;

void Start ()
{
    cN = 1;
}

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (cB == true)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("money = {0}", money);
            if (money >= 10)
            {
                buyCow();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("not enough money");
            }
        }
        else if (mB == true)
        {
        addMoney();
        }
        else
    {
        Debug.Log("Something is really wrong here");
    }
    }
    public void buyCow()
    {
        money = money - 10;
        cN++;
        Debug.LogFormat("cN = {0}", cN);
    }
public void addMoney()
{
    money += cN;
    Debug.LogFormat("money = {0}", money);
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you set cB somewhere? Believe bools default to false.

Comment: Yes, it is set outside of the code in the inspector for Unity, the problem is, even though the functions work, the variable value doesn't transfer.